# Switch from Windows Installer to Wix and Remove Previous Version

Tags: wix, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a Windows Setup Project for a WPF application, which referenced a project called 'x'. We have now done a major upgrade to the application, much of which involved restructuring the code and making it more MVVM. The installer project now references a project called 'y'. For some reason, using the Windows Setup Project, the product code is the same in the new version as it was in the previous version?
Because of how difficult it is each time to create the MSI using the Windows Setup Project, in that there are always duplicate references which need removing and references to files that don't exist, it was suggested by a colleague that we try out Wix.
I've therefore set up a Wix Setup project within the same solution, but what I need to ensure it does is to remove the existing version of the application (installed using the Windows Setup Project) before installing the new version using Wix. Is this possible?
I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119838/wix-installer-cant-upgrade-from-previously-installed-windows-installer-sw), but as I'm new to Wix, the answer isn't very clear.
Many thanks
Martin

Answer (score 1):

Definitely possible. Make sure you use the same UpgradeCode as your old MSIs, a newer Version and have a MajorUpgrade element it will work.

A new MSI project will give you all of the basics, and you just fill in the UpgradeCode and Version.

If you want to understand more, check out my [Deployment Dojo episodes on upgrading](https://youtube.com/live/IXc6_i0Pm4E).